# Resize images of different sizes in a flex layout according to their aspect ratio

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I have a 2-column flexbox layout and I'm trying to display four images of varying aspect ratios on the left column, but I can't seem to figure out how to get them to scale appropriately (without losing their aspect ratios) as the screen is resized. The 100% width of the parent element doesn't seem to be respected (the images just overflow).

I've got my rough code so far below. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row img {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.row:first-child img {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.row img {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/270x359" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/291x311" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/178x324" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/384x384" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>
      Some content
    </h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your can use

```
aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
```

property as well. and also

```
object-fit: cover;
```

these are also not widely supported but I think these should do the trick for you